# How to install GNU make in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, gnu

I am trying to install GNU make-3.82 on Windows 7. I downloaded the **make-3.82.tar.gz** setup but it does not have any setup file.

There is process given on [GNU site](http://petio.org/tools/make.html). But when I reach to the folder in **command prompt** and after extraction  write **./configure** it throws error

**is not recognized as internal or an external command, operable program or batch file.**

The installation procedure is given below but not able to understand how to make it. please help

[image]

Comment: Although using MinGW is a good solution, if you wanted to build GNU make yourself you certainly can.  However, you're reading the instructions for building GNU make on UNIX/POSIX systems like GNU/Linux.  If you want to build it on Windows you should read the instructions in the README.W32 file and follow those.  It's actually quite simple to build your own version of GNU make.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't bother doing that. Just install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), specifically MSYS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25480303/632951 ...

Answer (score 7):

You can find a standalone `make.exe` on this page:

http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=make

- Standalone executable, no DLL dependency.
- **Up-to-date** (contrarily to the [build](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) by GnuWin project, which [seems abandoned](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)).
- A 64-bit build is even offered.

Full credits go to the people of equation.com. Thanks to them :-)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays GNU Make ([DL](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/)) comes with `build_w32.bat` and even `sln` (Visual Studio solution) files.