# What is the equivalent to the Linux Install command for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

Running the `install` command in PowerShell gives me:

```
$ install
install : The term 'install' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ install
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (install:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Basically I want to provide a `make install` target for Windows developers. On linux, `make install` uses the `install` command to move it from a local path onto the system path. Is there an equivalent command to `install` for Windows users?

Comment: There isn't really an equivalent. Windows packages are generally either self-installing executables or archives in a particular format which are installed with `msiexec`. Source packages will normally be installed directly from the MakeFile.

Comment: make install for windows would be make install. see https://superuser.com/q/405158/132604 for example

Comment: @SampoSarrala that's not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't equivalent for GNU's `install`. However you can probably replace it just by copying the binaries and updating `%PATH%` variable accordingly.